# jquery-dirtyforms not working with ajax actionlink - UpdateTargetID

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, actionlink, jquery-dirtyforms

I have jquery.dirtyforms configured on all the forms in  my site. It works fine when the form is dirty and I try for example to close the page. But it doesn't work at all with an unobtrusive ajax call. (Ajax.ActionLink), the call just proceeds like normal.

Any ideas?

CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Create</title>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.2.1.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.dirtyforms.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $('form').dirtyForms();
      })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div id="update">
            <div class="form-horizontal">                
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", new AjaxOptions {UpdateTargetId = "update"})
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When the form is dirty, the Html.ActionLink triggers the Stay/Leave pop-up, but the Ajax.ActionLink just proceeds and loads the Index View in the desired div.
What I am trying to achieve is to trigger the dirtyforms pop-up also when clicking the Ajax.ActionLink.

Comment: Please show your code (including the code that is generated by viewing source). It is unclear from your question what you expect the `ActionLink` to do. Should it navigate? Should it post the form? If the former, you need to ensure the link that is added to the form is not ignored.  If the latter, you need to [attach your own event handler](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms#event-handler-customization) for Dirty Forms so it can intervene.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I just posted the code with some more information.